# To catch primefaces live scrolling event each time we reach end of scroll

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

Is there any way using which we can catch the live scrolling event each time we reach the end of scrolling and new set of records get loaded in the datatable.This would be very helpful to make some customizations similar to what we can do with sort,row select events.

Comment: Which component are you talking about? Can you post your code?

Comment: @Xtreme Biker:I am talking about catching the live scrolling event of primefaces datatable.With refrence to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082940/sorting-not-working-properly-with-primefaces-live-scrolling] that i have posted,my datatable sorting is not working properly.With new set of records getting loaded on reaching end of scrolling,the new records would be in unsorted order.I want to catch this end of scroll event and do something to make sure that sorting happens correctly.